# Report Builder 3.0: syntax error when trying to loop through list of report parameters

Tags: vba, function, reporting-services, sql-server-2008-r2, reportbuilder3.0

I'm trying to do the following:

1. Provide a list of available values for a parameter. User can select multiple values or none.
2. If a certain value exists in the list of selected parameters, show the corresponding column. If not, hide the column.

To do this, I wrote a custom function that takes in an integer, checks if this integer exists in the list of parameters, and outputs False/True to hide/show the column.

**Parameter Examples:**

```
Label          Value
Pallet         1
Item           2
.
.
.
nth-label      n
```

**The code:** Report Builder 3.0 is saying that I have a syntax error on line 8, but I'm not sure what it could be.

```
dim parm_array() as String
dim col_num as Integer 
dim i as Integer

function hide_column (ByVal col_num as Integer) as Boolean
    parm_array = Split(Join(Report.Parameters!show.Value,","), ",")
    for i in LBound(parm_array) To UBound(parm_array)
        if col_num = CInt(parm_array(i)) then 
            hide_column = 0
            exit for
        else
            hide_column = 1
        end if
    next
end function
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this directly in an expression with something like

```
=Array.IndexOf(Parameters!myParameter.Value, 1) > -1
```

**Note:** If you have left your parameter type as the default text then the expression will have to have the value quoted like this

```
=Array.IndexOf(Parameters!myParameter.Value, "1") > -1
```

or for readability we could use the parameter label instead of it's value

```
=Array.IndexOf(Parameters!myParameter.Label, "Pallet") > -1
```

You might need to reverse the result (i.e. <=-1) if the column visibility is doing the opposite of what you expected.